# Extra characters when sending String from Android client to Python Server

Tags: android, python, string, sockets, tcp

I am sending a String from an Android device to a python server via TCP socket, but when the message arrives on the server, there are extra characters in the front. For example, if I send the string

```
asdf
```

the result on the server would be

```
\x00\x13asdf
```

Anyone know why these characters are added to the front of the string? Is there a way to avoid this, or should I just cut these out at the server end?

For the reverse, the server sends

```
fdsa
```

The Android client receives

```
Nullfdsa
```

Client Code (Written in Android, Java):

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        TextView recieve;
        EditText addressText, portText, messageText;
        Button send, test;

        Socket socket = null;

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.fragment_customize_gateway, container, false);

            recieve = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            addressText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            portText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            messageText = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText3);

            send = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.send);
            send.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    AsyncTCPSend tcpSend= new AsyncTCPSend(addressText.getText().toString(),Integer.parseInt(portText.getText().toString()), messageText.getText().toString());
                    tcpSend.execute();
                }
            });
            return rootView;
        }

public class AsyncTCPSend extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            String address;
            int port;
            String message;
            String response;
            AsyncTCPSend(String addr, int p, String mes) {
                address = addr;
                port = p;
                message = mes;
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                Socket socket = null;
                try {
                    socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4999);
                    DataOutputStream writeOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    writeOut.writeUTF(message);
                    writeOut.flush();

                    ByteArrayOutputStream writeBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                    int bytesRead;
                    InputStream writeIn = socket.getInputStream();

                    while((bytesRead = writeIn.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        writeBuffer.write(buffer,0,bytesRead);
                        response += writeBuffer.toString("UTF-8");
                    }
                    response = response.substring(4);   //Server sends extra "Null" string in front of data. This cuts it out
                } catch (UnknownHostException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    response = "Unknown HostException: " + e.toString();
                    System.out.println(response);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
                    System.out.println(response);
                } finally {
                    if (socket != null) {
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                recieve.setText(response);
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }
        }
```

Server Code (In Python):

```
class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        #Connect to database
        try:
            from pymongo import MongoClient
            dbclient = MongoClient()
            db = dbclient.WDI_database
            print("Database Connected")
        except pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure as e:
            print("Database Failed: {}".format(e))

        col = db.users

        data2 = str(self.request.recv(1024), 'utf-8')
        print("Server: {}".format(data2));
        data = data2.split("||")
        try:
            #[2:] because we get two extra symbols in front of the username from Android
            username = data[0][2:] 
        except IndexError:
            username = ""
        try:
            password = data[1]
        except IndexError:
            password = ""
        try:
            camunits = data[2]
        except IndexError:
            camunits = 0
        try:
            homunits = data[3]
        except IndexError:
            homunits = 0
        post = {"user": username,
                "pass": password,
                "cam": camunits,
                "disp": homunits}
        col.insert(post)
        print(col.count())

        response = bytes("Received data for: {}".format(username), 'utf-8')
        self.request.sendall(response)

class ThreadedTCPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Port 0 means to select an arbitrary unused port
    HOST, PORT = "", 5000

    tcpserver = ThreadedTCPServer((HOST, PORT-1), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=tcpserver.serve_forever)
    server_thread.daemon = True
    server_thread.start()
    print("TCP serving at port", PORT-1)

    while True:
        pass
    tcpserver.shutdown()
```

Comment: TCP is a stream, what you send in one side you received at the other end, no more no less. Put the relevant code (send and recv) so we can help you detect where the problem might be.

Comment: Let me know if you want more code or information put into the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got some explanations about the extra characters.

In the java code, you are not getting an extra "Null" from the socket, the `response` string variable is not initialized, by default it is null, and you say

`response +=  writeBuffer.toString("UTF-8");`

so you append something to a null string, which happened  to be `"null" + something`.

I would initialize the variable in the declaration or just before the while loop:

`String response = "";`

In the Phyton code, I see nothing wrong, therefore I'd suggest you to write what you send to the Log and see if the extra characters are in the bytes you send.

Instead of `writeOut.writeUTF(message);`

try `socket.getOutputStream().write(message.getBytes());` // UTF-8 is the default.

and write it to the Log:

`android.util.Log.w("SENT", String.format("[%s] %d", message, message.length()));`

See the log to find out what you're really sending.

Comment: I changed writeOut.writeUTF(message) to what you suggested, and I am no longer receiving the extra characters. It appears that somewhere in the writeOut section causes the extra characters to be added to the string.

Answer (score 0):

Let java send the extra character. It did in my case too. 
I used -

data2 = data.strip()

if data2 == "(your desired data)"

//execution instructions

and so on.